# Is this a high-pass filter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, homework, high-pass-filter

I am not very sure about how to completely solve this question. I tried to calculate the equivalent impedance by C and R and got R/(1+jwRC). Then I calculated the transmittance by using the voltage divider rule and got G(w) = (1+jwRC)/(2+jwRC). Which shows me that at w=0, g = 1/2 and as w goes to infinity g approaches 1. Am I right? Is this enough for the solution? What about the characteristic frequence and magnitude/phase responses? Which type of filter is it?

[image]

Comment: It attenuates at low f and passes at high f so -6dB to 0 loss if no load

Comment: So could it be called a high-pass filter? Or there is a better name for it?

Comment: @FlávioMaia it's often called a "pre-emphasis filter" because of its time-domain response. But you shouldn't be expected to know that if you're taking a class that asks the question you shared.

Comment: [This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/555061/95619) is for a very similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the transfer function of this circuit is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{v}_\text{out}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)}=1-\frac{1}{2+\text{CRs}}\tag1$$

When working with sinusoidal signals, we can use \$\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=1-\frac{1}{2+\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}=1-\frac{2-\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}{2^2+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}=1+\frac{\text{CR}\omega\text{j}-2}{4+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\tag2$$

So, the absolute value is given by:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{2}{4+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\text{CR}\omega}{4+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\right)^2}\tag3$$

And the argument:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\arg\left(1+\frac{\text{CR}\omega\text{j}-2}{4+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\right)=\arg\left(1-\frac{2}{4+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}+\frac{\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}{4+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\right)=$$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{if}\space1-\frac{2}{4+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}=0\\
\\
\arctan\left(\frac{\text{CR}\omega}{2+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\right)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{if}\space1-\frac{2}{4+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}>0
\end{cases}\tag4$$

Now, it is not hard to see that:

$$\lim_{\omega\to0}\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{2}\tag5$$

And:

$$\lim_{\omega\to\infty}\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\lim_{\omega\to\infty}\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{2}{4+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\frac{4}{\text{CR}\omega}+\text{CR}\omega}\right)^2}=1\tag6$$

Answer (score 2):

> *Which type of filter is it?*

In the field of audio processing and tone controls it's a type of [shelving filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalization_(audio)#Shelving_filter): -

[image]

Ignore the red line - that is also a shelving filter but working at bass frequencies. Yours is equivalent to a treble shelving filter (blue line). Picture from [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Equalization_(audio)).

Of course, it needn't be associated with audio; it can be used in many signal processing applications. I've used one (converted into code) to counter the poor frequency response of a lame anti-alias filter in front of an ADC.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a high pass shelving filter as Andy says.

Whether it is or not depends on the load impedance. If that has a capacitive component it may be a compensated attenuator, such as found in a 10x scope probe.